# Computing: $ \lim_{(x,y)→(0,0)}\frac{(x^5+y^5)\ln(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$
\lim_{(x,y)→(0,0)}\frac{(x^5+y^5)\ln(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$
The answer is 0. Cannot seem to understand how the answer is 0.I know that the first part is 0 but I'm confused on how to deal with the natural log?

Why is squeeze theorem not a good approach? $0<|(x^5)<(x^2)^2|=|x|$ so $|x^5+y^5|<|(x^2+y^2)^2|$ so therefor 
$$0< \dfrac{|x^5+y^5|}{|(x^2+y^2)^2|}<1$$ then multiply both sides with $\ln(x^2+y^2)$. and take the $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \ln(x^2+y^2).$$ and since it is not $0$ but its negative infinity the limit doesn't exist by the squeeze theorem. which is not the right answer.

Comment: Try taking the exponential of the entire expression, find that limit and take logs of the limit.

Comment: Hint: convert the question to polar coordinates, then use L'Hospitals rule

Comment: We can over come this without polar coordinates solely by estimtes

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that by letting $x=\rho\cos(\theta)$ and $y=\rho\sin(\theta)$, we have that as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ then $\rho\to 0$ and
$$0\leq \left|\frac{(x^5+y^5)\ln(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\leq
\frac{(|\rho\cos\theta|^5+|\rho\sin\theta|^5)|\ln(\rho^2)|}{\rho^4}
\leq \frac{\rho^5(1+1)|\ln(\rho^2)|}{\rho^4}={4\rho|\ln(\rho)|}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: You dropped the absolute value around $\ln$

Comment: Yes, otherwise, it's wrong.

Comment: how were u able to get (cos (theta))^5+sin((theta))^5=1+1

Comment: @Andrew. Lower than

Comment: @Andrew Not $=$ but $\leq$. $|\cos (\theta)|\leq 1$ and $|\sin (\theta)|\leq 1$

Comment: Not equal, but $|(\rho\cos\theta)^5| = \rho ^5|\cos\theta|^5 \leq \rho^5$, because $|\cos|\leq 1$.

Comment: I see now why it is 0. Thank you.

Comment: @Wauzl Thanks for your comment about  the absolute value.

Comment: Why is squeeze theorem not a good approach?
0<|(x^5)<(x^2)^2|=|x| so |x^5+y^5|<|(x^2+y^2)^2| so therefor 0< |x^5+y^5|/|(x^2+y^2)^2|<1 then multilply both sides with ln(x^2+y^2). and take the lim (x,y) approch (0,0) of  ln(x^2+y^2). and since its not 0 but its negitive infinity the limit dosnt exist by the squeeze theorm. which is not the right answer.

Comment: You should consider the absolute value of $\ln(x^2+y^2)$ which goes to infinity. So the upper bound is correct but not useful.

Comment: So because 0 doesn't equal infinity squeeze theorem says that the limit doesn't exist and that means I need to try another approach then?

Comment: @Andrew So because $0$ doesn't equal to infinity, squeeze theorem can not be applied and that means we need to try another approach or a better estimate.

Answer (score 1):

For all norm we have $|x|, |y|\le \|(x,y)\|$

then we get $$|x^5+ y^5|\le 2\|(x,y)\|^5$$

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln x =  0$ and $\ln(x^2+y^2) = 2\ln\|(x,y)\| $  we obtain,
$$\left|\lim_{(x,y)→(0,0)}\frac{(x^5+y^5)\ln(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right| \le \lim_{\|(x,y)\|\to 0} 4\|(x,y)\|\left|\ln\|(x,y)\|\right| =0$$

Comment: I actually like this appoach better. Maybe it's helpful to replace $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ by $\|(x,y)\|\to 0$ to see that your last limit is just $\lim_{r\to0} 4 r |\ln r|$ by renaming $r=\|(x,y)\|$. This limit converges to 0, as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: Ok I have change the meaning does not change any way

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's do this properly: We use polar coordinates $x=r\cos \phi$ and $y=r\sin \phi$. We will try to use the sandwich (or squeeze) theorem:

\begin{align}
0&\leq \left|\frac{(x^5+y^5)\ln(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right| \\
 &= \frac{r^5|\cos\phi + \sin\phi|\cdot|\ln r^2|}{r^4} \\
 &\leq r\cdot(1+1)\cdot2\cdot|\ln r| = 4r |\ln r|.
\end{align}
We now need to show that $r|\ln r|\to 0$. For this we will use l'hospital's theorem (note that $|\ln r|=-\ln r$ for small $r$):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{r\to 0} r |\ln r| = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{-\ln r}{\frac1r} = “-\frac\infty\infty”\\
&\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{-\frac1r}{-\frac1{r^2}} = \lim_{r\to0} r = 0.
\end{align}
Since the latter limit converges, both limits are equal and therefore $r|\ln r|\to 0$ for $r\to 0$. And thusly, by the sandwich theorem, the limit you asked for converges to $0$.